# Assign account to other user

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I try to assign an account to another user using the assign button (standard microsoft) but I become this error:
Sql error: The operation attempted to insert a duplicate value for an attribute with a unique constraint. CRM ErrorCode: -2147012606 Sql ErrorCode: -2146232060 Sql Number: 2627

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeQ33.jpg]

Comment: Do you have any plugin or workflow on owner change or Assign message? Is this happening for every single account? Any new owner?

Comment: @ArunVinoth thank u for your response, i don't have any Plugin or workflow on owner change,and its is not happening for every  account?

Comment: then you have to find out the rootcause from the Account data that cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a duplicate or orphaned record in your PrincipalObjectAccess table. Are you on prem with access to SQL Server? You should check for an existing relationship in that table between the Account guid and User guid, and delete that row if so. If one IS orphaned you may need to also see if your Deletion Service cleanup job is running to completion. Best practice is to schedule that job to run during low usage times.

https://us.hitachi-solutions.com/blog/unmasking-the-crm-principalobjectaccess-table/

Deletion Service information: https://darrenliu.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/crm-2013-maintenance-jobs/

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen if you try and assign the problem record to a different user?

Does the user you are assigning the record to have full permissions to that record and any records that are used on that form via quick views etc?

This error may also be caused by entity alternate keys, if in use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/define-alternate-keys-reference-records

Also check the plugin trace logs just in case something is showing up in there that may help, although I know you have said you don't believe any Plugins or workflows are present it could be an OOTB one causing issues.